# independent identically distributed random variables, solution check

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3...$ be independent random variables with same distribution (iid). Let $P(X_1\geq 0)=1$ and $P(X_1=0)<1$

Prove that for every natural number $M$ the following is true:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i \geq M)=1$$

It can be shown that for large enough natural numbers $k$ $P(X_1 \geq \frac{1}{k})>0$ is true. I will use it later in solution.

My solution:

Let $A_n=${$w \in \Omega : \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i(w) \in [M,\infty)$}$=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i \geq M$

$$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P(A_n)=P(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n)=P(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i \geq M)=1-P(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i<M)\geq 1-P(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i={n \choose 2}+1}^{{n+1 \choose 2}}X_i<M)=1-\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}P(\sum_{i={n \choose 2}+1}^{{n+1 \choose 2}}X_i<M)=1-\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-P(\sum_{i={n \choose 2}+1}^{{n+1 \choose 2}}X_i\geq M))\geq 1-\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-P(n\max_{i \in {n \choose 2}+1 ... {n+1 \choose 2}}(X_i)\geq M))=1-\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-P(X_{j_n} \geq \frac{M}{n})(*)$$

From lemma from beginning: there exist $k$ such that $P(X_{j_n}) \geq \frac{1}{m})=s>0$ for all $m \geq k$. Let $m_0$ be such that $\frac{1}{k}>\frac{M}{m_0}$

Continue:

$$(*)\geq 1-\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-P(X_{j_n} \geq \frac{M}{m_0}) \geq 1-\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-P(X_{j_n} \geq \frac{1}{k})=1-\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-s)=1$$

Does this even make sense? I am just starting with random variables and independence so I am not even sure if these strings has sense. Is my solution correct?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't check your proof very carefully, but it is obviously overly complicated.  To prove it, an application of the second Borel-Cantelli lemma would be sufficient.

Since $P[X_1 > 0] > 0$ by assumption, it follows by the continuity of probability measure that there exists a $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $P[X_1 \geq \varepsilon] > 0$. It then follows by the i.i.d. assumption that
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty P(X_n \geq \varepsilon) = \lim_{N \to \infty}NP(X_1 \geq \varepsilon) = \infty,
\end{align}
which implies that $P[\limsup_n [X_n \geq \varepsilon]] = 1$ by the second Borel-Cantelli lemma.

Denote $X_1 + \cdots + X_n$ by $S_n$.  Because $\{X_n\}$ are non-negative, $S_n$ is nondecreasing hence its limit is well-defined.  Since $P[\limsup_n [X_n \geq \varepsilon]] = 1$, it is easy to see that $P[\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n = \infty] = 1$. That is, there exists $A \subset \Omega$ with $P(A) = 1$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}S_n(\omega) = \infty$ on $\omega \in A$. Now for fixed $M \in \mathbb{N}$, by the monotonicity of $S_n$, $[S_n \geq M]$ is nondecreasing and converges to the set $\bigcup_n[S_n \geq M]$, which contains the set $A$, hence by the continuity of probability again,
\begin{align}
P[S_n \geq M] \to P\left[\bigcup_n[S_n \geq M]\right] \geq P(A) = 1. 
\end{align}
This completes the proof.

Comment: Thank you for providing solutions, although I would really appreciate if you could check my solution even if it is overcomplicated

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting a little lost in the middle of the calculation where the sums over ${n \choose 2},...,{n+1 \choose 2}$ start showing up. There is a somewhat easier proof using Borel Cantelli. As you have astutely noticed, since the variables are positive $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(A_n) = P( \cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n)$. Notice that

$$
\{ X_{jMk+1} \ge 1/k,...,X_{(j+1)Mk} \ge 1/k, \mbox{ i.o. $j$}  \} \subseteq \{\mbox{  $\exists i \in \mathbb{N}$, } X_i \ge 1/k,...,X_{i+Mk} \ge 1/k  \}\subseteq \cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n. 
$$
i.o. $j$ here stands for ``infinitly often with respect to $j$".  Notice that the events $B_j = \{ X_{jMk+1} \ge 1/k,...,X_{(j+1)Mk} \ge 1/k\}$ are independent (why?). Hence we can apply the second Borel-Cantelli lemma (why?) to show that

$$
P(\{ X_{jMk+1} \ge 1/k,...,X_{(j+1)Mk} \ge 1/k, \mbox{ i.o. $j$}  \})=1. 
$$

Comment: The sums over binomials is because i want to have Independent variables X_1,X_2+X_3,X_4+X_5+X_6, and so on, these are triangular numbers: 1,3,6, and so on